# rdlc expression: Divide a value by the value above it in the table

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have an rdlc report that displays a table of values.  The way the report is sorted every other row is a sub type of the one above it.

The end user has requested that I add a column to the report that will display the results of dividing the given value on a row by the value that occurs immediately prior to it.

Adding this functionality on the DB end isn't feasable right now - it has to happen in the report.  Is this possible using an aggregate or custom expression?  Is there a way to obtain the value of the field that is above the one I'm working with?

Comment: So, I actually solved my problem by grouping by the record type, then creating an expression that summed the values in the group, and then subtracted the current value from the sum (which gives me the previous value).  Knowing that I can proceed.... but, it doesn't answer the question of the post.  Is there a way to obtain a specific value of a previous record in rdlc.  This solution only worked as all rows are matched pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in Reporting Services is an expression. You can do what you want with an expression that uses the Previous function which accesses the previous row. So make the value of your cell be an expression like:

```
=Fields!MyField.Value / Previous(Fields!MyField.Value)
```

Comment: Well, that was easy.  Thanks - learn a little more every day.